# Setting the right regex expression to use a PasswordFilter function

Tags: c++, winapi

**Original issue:**

I'm trying to deploy my own **password filter** DLL to match the four validation for a strong password (1 upper letter, 1 small-case letter, 1 number and 1 character). This is the code I have for the PasswordFilter function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(PUNICODE_STRING AccountName,
    PUNICODE_STRING FullName,
    PUNICODE_STRING Password,
    BOOLEAN SetOperation) {


    wstring passwordStringUnicode(Password->Buffer, Password->Length / sizeof(wchar_t));

    //Comparing password with the Regex.
    wregex regexExpression(L"Regex here!");
    if ((regex_match(passwordStringUnicode, regexExpression)) == FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried with this regular expression first:

> (?=^.{6,10}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,])(?!.*\s).*$

But the Users and Computers applet always says that it doesn't match the requirements. I tried with an easier regex: `(tulpep).(*)` and it worked with a password like this: **tulpepA1***

I tried with another one (`^(?=.​*[a-z])(?=.*​[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)`) and got: "Ivalid access to memory location".

So... can anyone help me to understand what the the problem is?

Comment: Could it be the string needs escaping? with std::quoted

Comment: I don't know, but the regex_match doesn't accept the quoted variable type. Any other idea?

Comment: Please do not post the answer in the question. Post the answer as an answer.

Comment: Got it. I will do that. A question: do you have anything to add to the answer? Is that OK?

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title. To indicate that your problem has been solved, accept an answer.

Comment: Have to wait 2 days to mark my own answer, but I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

The problem was the way I was writing the regular expression. I was able to fix it!

If anyone has the same problem, this worked for me:

```
wregex regexExpression(L"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\W).{6,10})");
```

So, the function would be something like this:

```
wregex regexExpression(L"((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\W).{7,20})");


    if ((regex_match(passwordStringUnicode, regexExpression)) == FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```